# Lambda expression as a class attribute?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

Is it possible to use a lambda expression as a class attribute?
I'm working on a little game in C++ where all bots have the same update routine, but everyone should have his own optional extra update routine.

I thought something like that

```
class Bot
{
private:
    Lambdatype lambda;

public:
    Bot(Lambda l) {lambda = l;} 
    update() { dosomething(); lambda(); }
};
```

Comment: BTW, it's spelled "lambda" :)

Comment: Every lambda expression has a unique type, so I don't think it's possible. Consider `auto x = []{}; auto y = []{}; std::is_same<decltype(x), decltype(y)>{} // yields false`.

Comment: @StilesCrisis Ah, thank you :) in early days I thought it would be spelled lambada

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), for example assume it's `void` function and gets two `int`:

```
class Bot
{
private:
    using Lambda = std::function<void(int, int) >;
    Lambda lambda;

public:

    Bot(const Lambda &l) : lambda(l)
    {
    }

    void update()
    {
        //dosomething...;
        lambda(1, 2);
    }
};

int main()
{
   Bot bot ([](int x, int y){ cout << x+y << endl; });

   bot.update();
}
```

More generic:

```
template <typename L>
class Bot
{
private:
    L lambda;

public:

    Bot(const L &l) : lambda(l)
    {
    }

    void update()
    {
        //dosomething...;
        lambda(1, 2);
    }
};

int main()
{
   Bot<std::function<void(int,int)>> bot (
                         [](int x, int y){ cout << x+y << endl; }
   );
   bot.update();
}
```

Template based:

```
template <typename L>
struct Bot
{
private:
   L lambda;

public:
   Bot(const L &l) : lambda{l}  {}
   void update() {  lambda(1,2); }
};

int main()
{
    auto l = [](int x, int y){ std::cout << x + y << std::endl; };

    Bot<decltype(l)> bot(l);

    bot.update();
}
```

Comment: Additional benefit: you're not restricted to lambda's now, you can store anything which has the correct signature.

Answer (score 1):

Addional you may use make_bot

```
template< class L >
struct bot
{
   bot( L l ) : lambda{l}  {}
   void update() {  lambda(1,2); }
private:
   L lambda;
};

template< class L > bot<L>  make_bot(L l ) { return {l}; }

int main()
{
   auto my_bot = make_bot( [](int x, int y){ std::cout << x + y << std::endl;} ) ;

   my_bot.update();
}
```

Comment: The problem with this technique is that each bot has its own lambda type, and therefore its own `bot<L>` type. That means you can't have a collection of bots anymore.

Comment: @MSalters. std::tuple to come for help :)